# DSP on MACOSX and iOS4

Tags: macos, ios4, signal-processing

I am a beginning electrical engineer(Analog) trying to understand the essence of DSP techniques. Things that interest me right now is filter implementations, FFT analysis on real time audio in general. I recently bought a MAC mini(OSX10.4 snow leopard) and inherited a jail broken iphone from my wife. I thought i could leverage the processing power in both the MAC and the iphone to create apps based on the available audio/DSP/math frameworks. I took a peek in to the various APIs such as Coreaudio,accelerate framework(vDSP) and got intimidated. I dont have any programming experience except for some matlab scripts and am totally new to the MAC paradigm(I used to be a PC).  Atleast i know that Objective-C is the programming language of choice for developing on the MAC platform and am prepping myself to learn that. How do i get started on the dsp aspects of audio on the MACOSX and iOS4 platforms? Any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you need to read through the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/performance/accelerateframework.html) for the Accelerate Framework if you want to do fast floating point calculations.

For me the CS193p stanford Lecture on iPhone Programming helped a lot to learn about the iOS frameworks and objective-c. Then again I already knew how to program C.
Anyway I recently used the vDSP framework to speed up my 3D-Engine and posted [some code](http://tacticadev.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/vdsp-on-ipod-3g-arm11/) on my blog, maybe that could help you too.